# when does Exim4 set $sender_address_data?

Tags: exim

In the [Exim documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html) for the use of sender=verify in an acl, the variable $sender_address_data is supposed to be set in an acl after a verify=sender option used in the RCPT acl: "If there is data in the $address_data variable at the end of routing, its value is placed in $sender_address_data at the end of verification."

But it is always blank for me. Under what conditions will $sender_address_data be non-empty?

Example:

```
acl_smtp_rcpt:
  ...
  accept
    authenticated = *
    verify = sender
    logwrite = authenticated user '$authenticated_id' sending as '$sender_address' which \
        is '$sender_address_data', if error: '$sender_verify_failure'
```

Results in log messages with the $sender_address_data always empty, and with no verify errors:

```
authenticated user 'user1' sending as 'alias1@example.com' which is '', if error: ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exim4 sets $sender_address_data only when $sender_address is set within a router **by the person writing the config file** and is not cleared by some other command by the end of the accepting router; exim itself never sets the value automatically. For example, this sets $address_data to the local part of the email address, and the value will be available as $sender_address_data in the acl that caused the routing or verification to occur:

```
acl_check_rcpt:
  ...
  accept
    authenticated = *
    verify = sender                                         # TRIGGER ROUTER
    logwrite = sender is local user '$sender_address_data'  # USE HERE
  ...

begin routers
 ...
 local_user:
   driver               = accept
   domains              = +local_domains
   check_local_user
   transport            = LOCAL_DELIVERY
   address_data         = ${local_part}                     # SET HERE
```